# How to manipulate the row name in tbl_regression?

Tags: r, gtsummary

in the example online, there is:

```
mod1 <- glm(response ~ trt + age + grade, trial, family = binomial)

t1 <- tbl_regression(mod1, exponentiate = TRUE)
```

It produces a nice regression table that works, but how can I write the code for just showing Grade 1 instead of all of the Grades 1 through 3. And, if there was a row that was inherently binary (0 or 1), how can I choose just the true one?

I tried the `label = list(.....)` and `value = list(...)`, but this is not an option I saw on the package information for `gtsummary`, and did not work when I tried. There must be an easy way to do this or I am not searching hard enough in the write-up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: Grade is a variable with three levels and you want to show this result on a single line.  You can use the Wald or Likelihood ratio test to test for the significance of Grade altogether and print the single p-value using the `combine_terms()` function. Note that you will no longer see the 2 beta coefficients associated with Grade II and Grade III.

Question 2: The `tbl_regression()` model will print the results as they were entered into `glm()`.  Numeric variables are interpreted as continuous and print on a single row. All others print on multiple rows. If you have a variable coded as 0/1, it will print on a single row. To show both levels, you can add `factor()` around it.  If you are in the opposite situation where you have a binary variable printing on multiple rows and want it shown on a single row, you can use the `tbl_regression(show_single_row=)` argument.

Example 1:
Show Grade on a single row, with default printing for `"trt"` (character) and `"death"` (numeric 0/1). `"trt"` prints on two rows, and `"death"` prints on a single row.

```r
library(gtsummary)
glm(response ~ trt + grade + death, trial, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  combine_terms(formula_update = . ~ . - grade, test = "LRT")
```

[image]

Example 2:
Now we will print `"trt"` on a single row, and `"death"` prints on two rows.

```r
glm(response ~ trt + factor(death), trial, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    show_single_row = trt,
    label = list(
      trt ~ "Drug B vs A (reference group)",
      `factor(death)` ~ "Death"
    )
  )
```

[image]